# How can one make every item in a list repeat on the same line in Bash

Tags: bash, list

Essentially, I am trying to use bash to change this:

```
(v) sleep#1

(v) nap#1

(v) doze#1
```

to this:

```
(v) sleep#1, sleep

(v) nap#1, nap

(v) doze#1, doze
```

As I see it, this involves somehow copying the word without the bracketed component, the hashtag, or the number, and inserting it after a comma-space. I am sure there is a way to do this with bash, but I haven't been able to get any results, as I am not entirely sure where to start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we assume the data is stored in a file called foo.txt, you could use sed like this

```
sed -E 's/(.*\))(.*)(#.*)/\1\2\3,\2/' foo.txt
```

Using -E, the non-escaped parentheses store whatever is matched into sequential variables accessed later as \*n* where *n* is the order they were matched.